# Datagrid SelectedItem binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to get the `SelectedItem` of a `DataGrid` but whenever i add the "SelectedItem.." that is commented out, my window does not show when i run the application. Is there something wrong with the binding?

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="40">
            <Label Content="Customer Table"/>
            <DataGrid Name="dgCustomer" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomerDataCollection}" 
                      IsReadOnly="True" 
                      TargetUpdated="dg_TargetUpdated"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      SelectionUnit="FullRow">
                <!--SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CustomerItemSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource}"-->
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="OrderID" Binding="{Binding OrderID, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
```

and I am using ObservableCollection

```
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> m_CustomerDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerAlcove> CustomerDataCollection
    {
        get => m_CustomerDataCollection;
        private set => Set(ref m_CustomerDataCollection, value);
    }

    private Customer m_CustomerItemSelected = new Customer();
    public Customer CustomerItemSelected
    {
        get => m_CustomerItemSelected;
        private set => Set(ref m_CustomerItemSelected, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to a readonly property (CustomerItemSelected has a private setter) with a OneWayToSource Binding. This will not work, so make your setter public:

```
public Customer CustomerItemSelected
{
    get => m_CustomerItemSelected;
    set => Set(ref m_CustomerItemSelected, value);
}
```